# Magento 2: How to get store logo in footer phtml?

Tags: magento2, system-configuration, logo

In magento 1 i could call the store logo in any template with something like this `Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/logo_src');`.

**How can I do the equivalent in Magento 2?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should inject the logo class  `\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Log` on your footer block class then You can get `$this->_logo->getLogoSrc()`

See at https://www.mageplaza.com/how-get-logo-url-alt-text-logo-size-magento-2.html

Or you can use logo path from

```
$block->getLayout()->getBlock('logo')->getLogoSrc()
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo")->setTemplate("Magento_Theme::html/header/logo.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```

You can try this one....